# Restful api + special characres

Tags: c#, rest

I have the following Rest interface:

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Save/servers/{serverName}/databases{databaseName}")]
        Task Save(string subscriptionId, string serverName, string databaseName, Stream policyStream);
```

I invoke using that client`s method

```
private async Task<RestResponse> SendRequestWithPayloadAsync(string verbName, string methodName, string requestBody, IEnumerable<object> parameters = null)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            string address = BuildAddress(methodName, parameters);

            if (requestBody == null)
            {
                requestBody = String.Empty;
            }

            byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);

            SetCertificateSettings(request);

            request.Method = verbName;
            request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
            request.ContentLength = payload.Length;

            // send request over the network
            using (Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                await dataStream.WriteAsync(payload, 0, payload.Length);
            }

            return await GetResponse(request, stopwatch, payload.Length);
        }
```

When the databaseName ends with "#" I don`t get it in Save method
For example if I send

```
databases\hgは常#
```

I get `hgは常` databases argument value.
Any ideas what causes that? and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is because '#' character is a special character when being used in URLs (you can find more information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier - There are more reserved characters - see the section of RFC 3986)

You should escape URLs using Percent-Encoding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

So, if you want to include a hash-mark (#) in your parameters - pass '%23' instead.